Is there a way to animate a looping texture moving across a surface?
I have a 3D model of a computer monitor with two image files for the screen's material:

a texture for the contents of the screen, and
a separate texture of horizontal lines that is multiplied with the first to simulate scanlines.

I want the scanline texture to continuously scroll vertically across the screen while wrapping around at the top and bottom. Is that possible?


I would use a mapping node into the vector input of your raster image and then use a driver to animate the direction of the raster based on the frame#.  You can add modulo to the expression if you want the raster to jump back at some regular frame count.   I scaled frame_current/22 to scale down the scan.

My example: 
